# Issue with BAM Continuation for BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, continuations

I have developed a BizTalk Application. It receives a xml file and, after applying the business logic, it sends the file to another location using FILE adapter. I need to track the start and end time for both Receive Port and Send Port. I have created BAM activities and view and have created a tracking profile using Tracking Profile Editor. I have used Interchange ID as continuation ID token.

The problem is that in the BAM tracking, I am getting two rows, one for the receive port and second for the send port. The continuation between the receive and send port is not working.

Comment: As you haven't provided us details of how you have configured it, it would be rather hard to say what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Continuation is not working most likely because InterchangeID is not naturally Promoted.

The small issue you have is that there is no naturally Promoted Property that can be used out of the box for this.

The simplest solution would be to create a custom Pipeline Component that Promotes InterchangeID (same property, just Promoted).  Then your Tracking Profile should start working.

FYI, it this point, you don't really need BAM as it's pretty easy to query tracking directly using the same Promoted Property (which is what BAM is essentially doing using a slightly different path).

Answer (score 0):

The interchange id will be present in the message context. Can you please confirm you mapped receive and send ports to the continuations in the tracking profile editor. Refer the article https://www.biztalk-server-tutorial.com/2013/02/08/how-to-enable-bam-continuation-between-receive-send-ports-using-tracking-profile-editor/ which shows the steps to add continuation correctly.